# getContentURL method for fetching contents for OpenCmis not working

Tags: java, opencmis

I am new to opencmis client. My requirement is to get the urls for the uploaded documents through opencmis client. I am basically trying to fetch the urls by the following code:

```
Document document= (Document)cmisSession.getObject(docuementID);
String link = document.getContentUrl();
```

I am able to get other properties.
Binding Type of my parameters is WEBSERVICES.

Is it possible to get the content url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Webservices binding does not support content URLs. If you can, switch to the Browser binding. It supports content URLs and is significantly faster overall.